# Commuting graphs of groups

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, graph-theory, optimization, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a group and $S \subset G$ is its finite subset. Let’s define the *commuting graph* of $G$ in respect to $S$ as $Comm(G, S)$ - a graph, where the vertices are the elements of $S$, and they are connected with edges iff they commute.

Let’s define the *commuting graph representation number* as the minimal number $CGRN(n)$, such that any $n$-vertex graph is isomorphic to a commuting subgraph of some group of order $CGRN(n)$.

My question is:

> Is there some exact formula (or at least asymptotic) for $CGRN(n)$?

The only thing that I managed to prove, were the following bounds (which is quite a weak result, as the lower bound is linear, but the upper bound is exponential):

> $$\frac{8(n-1)}{5} \leq CGRN(n) \leq 4^n$$

The proof of the lower bound:

According to Erdos-Turan-Gustafson theorem any commuting graph on a non-abelian group $G$ has clique number not exceeding $\frac{5}{8}G$. And it is quite obvious, that if $G$ is abelian, then all its commuting graphs are complete. So, if we have a graph with $n$ vertices and the clique number $n-1$ (to get such graph, you may remove any single edge from $K_n$), then the minimal group, such that this graph is a commuting graph in $G$ must have order at last $\frac{8(n-1)}{5}$.

The proof of the upper bound:

For any $n$ vertex graph $\Gamma(V, E)$, where $V = \{1, 2, … n\}$ such group and the corresponding subset can be explicitly constructed as

$$G = \langle \{a_v\}_{v \in V} | \{a_v^4 = e\}_{v \in V}, \{a_ua_v = a_va_u\}_{(v, u) \in E}, \{a_ua_va_u = a_v\}_{(u, v)\notin E, u \leq v} \rangle$$
$$S = \{a_v\}_{v \in V}$$

Comment: Where are you getting your $5/8$ bound? I think the correct bound is $1/2$: the center is at most $1/4$ so you must have a non-central element in your set, and its centraliser has size at most $1/2$ (it is a proper subgroup).

Comment: Anyway, the correct bound for the graph under discussion ($K_n$ minus an edge) is $4(n-2)$. Note that we can assume that, WLOG, we can assume that $G$ is generated by $S$. In particular, the $n-2$ universal vertices are in the center, so $|G|\geq 4(n-2)$ (since the center has index at least $4$). It's also quite easy to build examples where this bound is met. So this is a lower bound. I also tried a few other graphs (for example, an edgeless graph) but these give worse bounds. I have no idea what growth to expect in general...

Comment: Using similar ideas, I think I can get a quadratic lower bound. Take the graph consisting of a core of $n-k$ universal vertices, and $k$ vertices joined only to this core. Now, by the same argument as above, we find that $|Z(G)|\geq n-k$. On the other hand, when we project to $G/Z(G)$, the $k$ vertices should project to distinct elements, otherwise they would commute. It follows that $|G/Z(G)|\geq k+1$. Combining these, we find $|G|\geq (n-k)(k+1)$. Choosing $k=n/2$ gives that $|G|> n^2/4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to prove an improved upper bound of $2^{n+1}$.

Take the same graph on $n$ vertices as in your example, and consider the following group:

$G=\left\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n,z| a_i^2=z^2=[a_i,z]=1\quad \forall i, [a_i,a_j]=\begin{cases} 1 \quad\textrm{if \{i,j\} is an edge} \\ z \quad\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}\right\rangle$.

I believe this group has order $2^{n+1}$ and taking $S=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ will give the desired graph.

Using a computer, I checked that for $C_4\cong K_{2,2}$, the smallest group indeed has order $32$ (and arises essentially in this way), so this bound is tight for $n=4$.

EDIT:
Combined with the answer at 
[Minimal possible order of a group that contains a specific subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3395225/minimal-possible-order-of-a-group-that-contains-a-specific-subset/3395358#3395358)
this shows that $2^{n+1}$ is the correct bound (at least for $n$ even).